# How to login yetanotherforum with my websites login?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, yetanotherforum, yaf

I have a ASP.NET MVC3 website. I integrated Yaf 1.9.6.1 into my website's `/forum` folder successfully. And I have same users in my two user tables. How Can I login yaf with my web sites login?

Comment: I think the Session & Cookies could be shared between your site and the Yaf.

Comment: @allentranks Thanks for your comment. I think session & cookies could be shared too. but I couldnt find yaf cookies. I need code.

Comment: I need help. Doesnt anybody know?

Comment: @sbayd Is it necessary to have two different user tables since I assume your forum and website is on save server?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.

I created machine key and I used it on application and child application's web config.

And I used yaf.net cookie in my login page.

This is my code:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, Form.email, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, "", "/");
string strEncTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(".YAFNET_Authentication", strEncTicket);
authCookie.Path = "/";
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```